# Non-Slider Numeric Range Input

Tags: r, shiny

I’m working on an app which dynamically renders a set of UI elements (currently sliders) into three columns based on the user selecting which metrics they’d like to filter a particular dataset on. The issue I’m running into is that the different metrics have wildly variable ranges (i.e. gross merchandise sales vs. customer return rate) meaning sliders aren’t the best to work with. I’m wondering if any of you are aware of a numeric range input that can take two numeric inputs (a min and max) similar to the ends of a range slider? I haven’t been able to find something built into Shiny with this capability, but am hoping one of you may have some experience with customizing input elements. Any help will be greatly appreciated. See below for a snippet demonstrating the dynamic slider generation.

Thanks!

```
output$filters <- renderUI({
if (input$geoselect == "US") {
  atts <- tolower(input$ucolselect)
 if(length(input$ucolselect) >= 3) {

  fluidRow(column(width = 4, lapply(1:round(
    1 / 3 * length(atts)
  ), function(i) {
    sliderInput(
      inputId = atts[i],
      label = atts[i],
      min = min(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE),
      max = max(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
      ,
      value = c(min(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE), max(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE)),
      step = NULL
    )
  })),
  column(width = 4,

         lapply((1 + round(1 / 3 * length(atts))):round(2 / 3 * length(atts)), function(i) {
           sliderInput(
             inputId = atts[i],
             label = atts[i],
             min = min(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE),
             max = max(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
             ,
             value = c(min(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE), max(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE)),
             step = NULL
           )
         })),
    .....
```

Answer (score 2):

A feature like this called `numericRangeInput()` was just added to `shinyWidgets` (https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/pull/150). It's not on CRAN yet but you can install the development version from GitHub.

```
devtools::install_github("dreamRs/shinyWidgets")

output$filters <- renderUI({
  if (input$geoselect == "US") {
    atts <- tolower(input$ucolselect)
    if (length(input$ucolselect) >= 3) {
      fluidRow(column(width = 4, lapply(1:round(
        1 / 3 * length(atts)
      ), function(i) {
        numericRangeInput(
          inputId = atts[i],
          label = atts[i],
          value = c(min(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE), max(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE))
        )
      })),
      column(width = 4,
             lapply((1 + round(1 / 3 * length(atts))):round(2 / 3 * length(atts)), function(i) {
               numericRangeInput(
                 inputId = atts[i],
                 label = atts[i],
                 value = c(min(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE), max(us[, tolower(colnames(us)) %in% atts[i]], na.rm = TRUE))
               )
             })),
```

UPDATE: `numericRangeInput()` is now on CRAN in `shinyWidgets` 0.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Why not `numericInput`? This also include min, max and step values. But as i know, you can type in value that greater than max or lower than min, so better to manage it on server with `updateNumericInput()` and back values in min:max range in code. Hope i understand you rigth and this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I'm looking for something a bit different. The issue is that I have a few variables with two large of a range to make dragging a slider feasible (i.e. sales from 0 to $238 MM). What I'd like is a paired set of numericInputs that set the upper and lower limits to filter on, without actually having to create two separate inputs per user selected variable. Hence, something like a dateRangeInput that takes free form numeric input instead.